# Sending a pair of coordinates in $[0,1]^2$ using a small number of bits

Tags: probability, random-variables, polar-coordinates, estimation, compression

Consider a random variable $X$ that is uniform on $[0,1]^2$.

I want to send this variable to a receiver, using $2k$ bits, with an encoding $Y$.

The receiver knows the prior distribution and when receiving $Y$, it estimates the original value as $\widehat {X}$.

> **If we aim to minimize the expected error $||X-\widehat {X}||$ (say, for an $L_2$ norm), what'd be the right encoding and decoding schemes?**

---

A simple solution would be to encode each coordinate of $X$ using $k$ bits as $Y=(X_1\cdot 2^k, X_2\cdot 2^k)$ (rounding deterministically or randomly) and estimating $\widehat X=(2^k/Y_1, 2^k/ Y_2)$.

However, some simulations suggest that by switching to a [polar representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) (i.e., sending the approximated polar representation and decoding it accordingly) we can get a lower expected error (in terms of both $L_1$ and $L_2$ norms).

> What is the right generalization to $[0,1]^d$ variables for a larger $d$?

Comment: I think you mean $Y = (2^kX_1,2^kX_2)$, rounded, and $\widehat{X} = (2^{-k}Y_1, 2^{-k}Y_2)$.

Comment: @orlp -- you're right, thanks!

Comment: A few comments. The receiver gets one of $2^{2k}$ strings, each of which is reconstructed to a certain point in $[0,1]^2$. In other words, there is a set $A\subseteq[0,1]^2$ of size $2^{2k}$ such that each $X\in[0,1]^2$ is encoded as an element of $A$. It is obvious that for a fixed $A$, the expected error is minimized if $X$ is encoded as the *nearest* element of $A$. Thus, the goal is to find a set $A\subseteq[0,1]^2$ of size $2^{2k}$ such that the expected distance of a random point of $[0,1]^2$ to $A$ is minimized. Note that the partition of $[0,1]^2$ according to which point it is ...

Comment: ... mapped to is then just the Voronoi tesselation corresponding to $A$. If $A$ minimizes the expected distance, then each point of $A$ must be the barycenter of its Voronoi cell. (By the way, a set $A$ minimizing the expected distance *exists*, because the expected distance is a continuous function of $A$ considered as an element of the compact space$([0,1]^2)^{2^{2k}}$.) Making a huge leap of faith, this baryceter property suggests that the optimum shuold be attained by a *regular* tesselation (ignoring complications near the boundary of $[0,1]^2$). There are only 3 regular tilings of ...

Comment: ... the plane: by equilateral triangles, by squares, and by regular hexagons. It is easy to see that in a regular polygon of fixed area (here, $2^{-2k}$), the expected distance from the center gets smaller as the number of sides increases. Thus, out of the three regular tesselations, the minimal one should be the hexagonal tiling. So, all in all, I believe that the optimal (at least asymptotically as $k\to\infty$) encoding is to tile $[0,1]^2$ by $2^{2k}$ regular hexagons of area $2^{-2k}$ (modifying them in some reasonable way at the boundary), and encode $X$ by the center of the hexagon ...

Comment: ... it falls into. Note that this makes $A$ into the set of centers of the hexagons in the tiling, which form the vertices of a regular triangular grid.

Comment: And while this is not quite the same problem as sphere packing, Kepler’s conjecture suggests that the optimal encoding for $d=3$ should be given by the hexagonal packing, and that there is no readily available generalization to higher dimensions.

Comment: The above is not quite correct: the barycenter minimizes the expected *squared* distance. But anyway, if $C$ is the Voronoi cell corresponding to $u\in A$, the “center” of $C$ minimizing the expected distance is usually different from $u$, unless the Voronoi tesselation is regular. Thus, the basic heuristics still applies.

Comment: I see: if we want to miminize expected *squared* distance, the optimal configurations are given by what is known as centroidal Voronoi tesselations, and in 2D, it is indeed known that the asymptotically optimal CVT is the regular hexagonal tesselation (this is the 2D case of Gersho’s conjecture). See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2004.12.008 , https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1982.1056492 .